# How to calculate distance from point to nearest polygoin via road network (polyline) ARCMap 10.3.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, distance, network-analyst, road

Using ArcMap, is it possible calculate distance from a postcode (point) to nearest polygon using a road network layer (polyline)? As opposed to just calculating Euclidean distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the Network Analyst Extension.

- Build a network using your road layer (requires network analyst extension)
- Identify nearest polygon using point distance tool or near tool (or use existing point if known)
- Add nearest polygon point and postcode point as stops in the network solver
- then compute a route distance from your post code point to the nearest polygon. **Total_length** gives you distance along road. see sample below.

---

[image]